# JSON formatting "$ref" error

Tags: json, json-schema-validator

I am trying to find what is making the following JSON invalid. The strange thing is that it passes off as valid JSON in [this](http://jsonschemalint.com/) website but is invalid in [this](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) one

Here's the schema:

http://pastebin.com/QPxEPjMT

The error logged on the second schema validation website is as follows:

```
Error when resolving schema reference '#/definitions/identifiable'. 

Path 'definitions.subscription.allOf[0]', line 19, position 17.
```

Can someone clarify whether my schema is incorrect or this is about some ambiguous rule in the JSON Schema itself?

Comment: In the http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ website you provided if you choose "schema draft v3" or "schema draft v4" and the json is validated as good. Additionally, in jslint.com (which is what I use) your json is valid.

Comment: @AshwinKrishnamurthy appreciate the response but when you select v4 from the dropdown, the website loads up some default schema.

Comment: My apologies. I believe I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the schema defined for the object of type 'identifiable' on the root definitions level:

```
 {
    ...
    "definitions": {
         ...
        "identifiable": {
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "id": "http://api.sprint.com/schema/identifiable#",
                "title": "Identifiable Schema",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "READ ONLY. The id of the resource."
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "id"
                ],
                "additionalProperties": true
        ...
  }
...
}
```

But you have it defined inside your definition of the object of type 'subscriptions'. So, the reference you have in the scheme is pointing to:

```
[root]/definitions/identifiable
```

but you have it on:

```
[root]/definitions/subscriptions/definitions/identifiable
```

Please, fix your reference.
BTW, both of sites are marking your schema invalid.