# $ref not working from array type json schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, ajv

I have three json-schema definitons.
client, address and contact.

client.json

```
{
  "$id": "client.json",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "$id": "/properties/name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
      "$id": "/properties/id",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "contact": {
            "$ref": "contact.json"
    },
    "address": {
        "$ref": "address.json"
    }
  }
}
```

address.json

```
{
  "$id": "address.json",
  "type": "array",
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "items": {
    "$id": "/items",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "addressId": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/addressId",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "addressName": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/addressName",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

contact.json

```
{
  "$id": "contact.json",
  "type": "array",
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "items": {
    "$id": "/items",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "contactId": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/contactId",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "contactName": {
        "$id": "/items/properties/contactName",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "address": {
          "$ref": "address.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

object To be validated

```
var client = {
    "name": "test",
    "id": 12,
    "contact": [
        {
        "contactId": 12212,
        "contactName": "jon",
        "address": [
            {
                "addressId": 64,
                "addressName": "pi"
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "address": [
        {"addressId": 4242,
        "addressName": "doe"}
    ]
};
```

$ref's from 'client.json' work fine but I get an error on referring 'address.json' from 'contact.json'.
I get no errors on using $refs inside of 'additionalItems' but fails to validate against schema pointed by $ref's.

I wish to know how do I use $ref from an array type schema definition.
Also, I'm using AJV for schema validation.

**Edit 1:** 
AJV setup

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv({
    $data: true,
    allErrors: true,
    useDefaults: true, 
    coerceTypes: true, 
});

ajv.addSchema(client);
ajv.addSchema(contact);
ajv.addSchema(address);

let valid = ajv.validate('client.json', payload);

if(!valid){
    console.log(ajv.errors);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would give you an error. Can you provide some code where you set up and use ajv? Then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Oh! yes @Relequestual

Comment: Seems valid to me! I'll ping Evgeny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is that `$id` changes the resolution scope of the `$ref`. I'm guessing `$ref` resolution is happening by looking for files on the file system. Let's assume your three schemas are available at `file:///path/to/schema`.

1. You start processing the `file:///path/to/schema/client.json` schema.
2. You encounter the reference `contact.json`. This is relative URI, so you need to determine the URI it is relative to in order to resolve it.
3. You backtrack up the schema and you find the nearest `$id` with value `client.json`.
4. This is a relative URI and there are no more `$id`s, so the file's path, `file:///path/to/schema/client.json` is used.
5. You can now resolve `client.json` against `file:///path/to/schema/client.json` and get `file:///path/to/schema/client.json`.
6. You can now resolve `contact.json` against `file:///path/to/schema/client.json` and get `file://path/to/schema/contact.json`.

Here's where it starts to get weird.

1. You retrieve the `file:///path/to/schema/contact.json` schema.
2. You encounter the reference `address.json`. This is a relative URI, so you need to determine the URI it is relative to in order to resolve it.
3. You backtrack up the schema and you find the nearest `$id` with value `/items`.
4. This is a relative URI, so you keep backtracking and find `contact.json`.
5. This is a relative URI and there are no more `$id`s, so the file's path, `file:///path/to/schema/contact.json` is used.
6. Now you can resolve `/items` against `file:///path/to/schema/contact.json` and get `file:///items`.
7. Now you can resolve `address.json` against `file:///items` and get `file:///address.json`.
8. You attempt to retrieve the `file:///address.json` schema, but it doesn't exist.

Because `$id` changes resolution scope of `$ref`, it's highly discouraged to give everything an `$id` like you have done in your schemas. This feature exists for use cases like combining multiple small schemas into one. You should really never use it other than at the root of the document unless you have a really good reason and understand the implications.

Comment: Thank you! @Jason. $ref's work on removing items $id . I've been using online schema generators so $ids came with schemas itself and never thought of removing $ids considering them harmless.

Comment: Check this answer too for better understanding how $ref works when id is used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595377/json-schema-regarding-use-of-ref