# What does "$ref": "#" mean?

Tags: jsonschema, ref

Here is sample JSON schema code:
What is "$ref": "#"  referring to? 
Is it here? or do they mean the whole document?
You can find this entire schema on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net
Select Schema Draft V7.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
 "definitions": {
    "schemaArray": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": { "$ref": "#" }
    },
    "nonNegativeInteger": {
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 0
    },
    "nonNegativeIntegerDefault0": {
        "allOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/nonNegativeInteger" },
            { "default": 0 }
        ]
    },....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert, but I had same question and I think I found answer

> ... each $ref is resolved into a full URI. Once that is done, all your questions are answered by asking the question: What schema would I end up with, if I simply fetched that URI? Where the $ref is, how it was loaded, all of that is irrelevant - it's entirely dependent on the resolved URI.
>
> The library might take some shortcuts (like caching documents so they are only fetched once, or trusting one schema to "speak for" another), but those are all implementation details.
>
> # is not special: all values of $ref are resolved as URIs relative to the current document (or the closest value of "id", if there is one).
>
> Therefore, if you haven't used "id", then # will point to the root of the schema document. If you fetched your schema from http://example.com/schema, then a {"$ref": "#"} anywhere inside that will resolve to http://example.com/schema#, which is the document itself.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723151/989369

So basically it points to main scheme, i.e.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
 "definitions": {
    "schemaArray": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": { "$ref": "#" }
    }
```

will convert to:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
 "definitions": {
    "schemaArray": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
          "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
          "definitions": {
          ...
        }
    }
```